# How does the stiffness of semicircular beams connected in series increases?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, deflection

I am working to reduce the deflection in a cantilever/ dive board at work.$300 mm(L) \times 30mm(B) \times 2 mm(H)$, i.e. it's a rectangular cross section currently.

I can't change the material, or length.

I started  playing with cross sections to reduce the deflection. So I stacked 7 semi circular beams of 4mm Dia. next to each other(thus not changing the height from rectangular beam) assuming it would increase my "I" by 7 X I of single semi circular beam, thus making it stiffer than the current beam but IT DID NOT. Any idea why?

Calculations:

- I(Rectangular cross section): $bh^3/12= 20 mm^4$
- I (single Semicircular Beam of Dia 4)= $\pi \cdot r^4/8= 6.28 mm^4$

Again, I assumed stacking up next to each other would make the total area moment of inertia(I) = $7 \cdot 6.28 = 43.96 mm^4.$

And Using Deflection  = $FL^3/48EI$, I thought it would decrease my deflection by more than half.IT DIDN'T WORK. FEA results showed increase in deflection.

Any idea why? Sorry if it's a dumb question

Comment: Think you need diagrams as first you say in series then next to each other. Just can’t be sure of what you describe.

Comment: If I understood correctly, (
and continuing from Solar Mikes's comment), Did you replace the one beam with cross-section 30mm x 2mm with 7 half circles of diameter 2mm stacked along side?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly from your post you started with the following cross-section (Lets say A)

[image]

and you replaced it with the following (or the inverted) (let's call it B).

[image]

There is one reason why you are getting larger deflections,

> the total second moment of area is smaller.

### Crosssection A

The total second moment of area for Cross-section A along axis X is:

$$I_{xx,A} = \frac{bh^3}{12} = 20[mm^4]$$

### Crosssection B

For cross-section B, the actual moment of area is -indeed- 7 times the moment of area for the semi-circle (SC).
$$I_{xx,B}  =7 \cdot  I_{xx, SC}$$

However, the semi-circle $I_{xx, SC}$, is given [by (see wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_second_moments_of_area) :
$$ I_{xx, SC}= 0.1098r^4$$

[image]

Therefore the total $I_{xx,B}=12.3 mm^4$.

---

### Comparison

According to the above you should expect approximately 60% more deflection from case B, because:

- $I_{xx,A}=20  mm^4$
- $I_{xx,B}=12.3 mm^4$

However that was to be expected because, if you put the two cross-section together you'd see that cross-section A encapsulates B.

[image]

-

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes in your hand calculation:

**1) Wrong equation was used to calculate the moment of inertia** - you used the equation for $I_y$ instead of $I_x$, thus resulting in the hand calculation being larger than the calculation done by the FEM program ($I_y$ > $I_x$).

[image]

$I_x = \frac{(9\pi^2 -64)r^4}{72\pi} \approx 0.1098r^4$

$I_y = \frac{\pi r^4}{8} = 0.3927r^4$

**2) Wrong equation was used for the deflection calculation.**

[image]

The equation you have used corresponds to a simply supported beam with a concentrated load in the mid-span.

[image]

Thus, the FEM reported a much larger deflection than you had anticipated.

Please keep in mind, the correct/successful design of a diving board is quite involved, which shouldn't be contemplated by an amateur without being mentored, or supervised by a knowledgeable person.